# Why doesn't this Synchronize procedure lock the main thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe2

I have following code:

```
TThread.Synchronize(nil,
  procedure
  begin
    with Scope.New(TManualCaptchaForm.Create(img)) do
      if It.ShowModal() = mrOk then
        res := It.edtResolved.Text;
  end
);
```

Why does the form appear several times when multiple `TThreads` use this procedure for synchronization? I know a workaround, and there is nothing unusual (e. g. no other "hand-made" ways  to sync with main thread), but ***why am I not experiencing a lock?***

---

Yes, `Scope.New` is kinda smart-pointer, ***BUT*** only i see `TThread.Synchronize` and passed closure? Documentation says that any method/closure passed to  `TThread.Synchronize` will be execute inside main thread.  Obviously, `ShowModal` must block main thread, but it didn't do that. As for me, it's very strange that any other window start behave as main thread and pump synchronization queue.

P. s. almost MVP:

```
TThread.Synchronize(nil,
  procedure
  var Form: TForm1;
  begin
    Form := TForm1.Create(nil);
    try
      Form.ShowModal();
    finally
      Form.Free;
    end;
  end
);
```

Run this code in 2+ threads and see bug. Anyway, now I know that synchronization queue pumped by any window message loop, not just by main form.

Btw, my question was "Why `TThread.Synchronize` behave so unclear/not logically?", not about my own code.

Comment: We need to see more code.  What is `Scope`?  What does `Scope.New` do ?  What does it return?  What is `It`?  Consider making a [mcve].

Comment: I don't see any code here which would make it execute many times. Surely it's in the code we cannot see.

Comment: Having more than 1 thread calling this code would be one reason...

Comment: Looks like some smart pointer implementation where `Scope.New` wraps the passed instance into some lifetime guard and `It` provides access to the wrapped instance. However if properly implemented it should not cause several appearances of the form.

Comment: Even with your edit I'm not sure what bug you are experiencing. As of the title of the question, you are wondering why the method you are providing as a Synchronize parameter is blocking your main thread?

Comment: @Nil, no, why my method ***not blocking main  thread***? He definitely must block main thread and all further calls of `Synchronize`, but he didn't do  that. I look into VCL sources and now know why is so. Topic closed, thnx for trying to help me.

Comment: @Green_Wizard Your edit was good - I think it is clear now what you are asking.  The question is reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental misunderstanding here is that because `.ShowModal` is a blocking call you *expect* that it also suspends message processing.  It does not.  When you create a modal window the modal window takes over message processing - it must do this or the window would not function.  The main thread is still processing the message loop, it is just doing it in a different context.

If you want to think of it this way, `ShowModal` behaves a lot like `Application.ProcessMessages`.  This has nothing to do with `Synchronize`.  If you examine the code for `ShowModal` you find :

```
  {  ...  }
  Show;
  try
    SendMessage(Handle, CM_ACTIVATE, 0, 0);
    ModalResult := 0;
    { *** Here is your message loop *** }
    repeat
      Application.HandleMessage;
      if Application.Terminated then ModalResult := mrCancel else
        if ModalResult <> 0 then CloseModal;
    until ModalResult <> 0;
    { *** ------------------------- *** }
    Result := ModalResult;
    SendMessage(Handle, CM_DEACTIVATE, 0, 0);
    if GetActiveWindow <> Handle then ActiveWindow := 0;
  finally
    Hide;
  end;
  {  ...  }
```

If you want to prevent reentrance here you have to devise your own explicit method to do so.